# how to save any file in specific folder in c# programatically

Tags: c#, sql, database-backups

I want to save my backup file in specific folder. currently I'm using a `saveFileDialog` box to give `path` and file name on a `button click`. But I want to create this backup by giving name as `(DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString())` and save this in `"D:\Database"` directly on `button` click. and don't want to use `saveFileDialog` box. I'm using this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER BACKUP DATABASE plproject TO DISK = '" + saveFileDialog1.FileName + "'", connectionsql);
```

Comment: what you want, please clear

Comment: just got it, but what is the issue, if you are using `DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: currently I give path by saveFileDialog box but if I don't use saveFileDialog box, I don't know how can give the path and file name

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking here, you can directly replace `saveFileDialog1.FileName` with `DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: So where can I find that file?

Comment: you can replace your folder path here and can use - [your folder path] `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER BACKUP DATABASE plproject TO DISK = '[your folder path]" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'", connectionsql);`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this

```
public static void WriteAllText(
    string path,
    string contents
)

File.WriteAllText("D:\\DataBase\\"+DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString(),YOURDATASTRING);
```

Note: It will overwrite any file with same name.

There are many other useful methods available in [FILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class. You can check which suits you best.

EDIT  1

Try this

```
string fileName="D:\\Backup\\"+DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER BACKUP DATABASE plproject TO DISK = '" + fileName + "'", connectionsql);
```

Comment: so how can I use this in my command, please edit my sql command with your code

Comment: my message box show me Successful but there is no file created in backup folder.